# D3.js v7: interpolate translate/scale with new position?

Tags: d3.js

I have a graph of several nodes and edges. I used a layout algorithm (elkjs) to calculate the position of the nodes and edges. The graph is fairly large, with 268 nodes and 276 edges, such that:

```
svg width: 800, height: 600; graph width: 1844, height: 3007
```

As such, I had to do the requisite math to calculate pan offsets and scaling so it would fully fit, centered in the viewport:

```
translate(225.228, 15) scale(0.1896)
```

I programmatically transition it into place over 2500ms - it works fine and fits nicely.

But then I wish to switch to a subgraph, picking a node to see only it and its descendants. This particular example subgraph is near the bottom of the graph, so the starting position of its y-values are relatively large. After I call the layout algorithm again to get the new positions, the repositioned graph is smaller:

```
svg width: 800, height: 600; graph width: 874, height: 459
```

I then do the join/enter/update/exit thing to update the positions over a duration (and remove the other elements not in the subgraph), and I also do the math again for pan offsets and scaling:

```
translate(20, 100.4348) scale(0.8696)
```

Here's the problem: while it does end up in the right place, it pans off-screen before panning back on-screen:

[image: Subgraph pans off screen, then on]

I think I see why: the re-positioning transition has the same duration (2500ms) as the panning/scaling, and something about that all combined has that undesirable effect. I'm able to keep the subgraph on-screen by making the positioning happen faster:

```
rects
  .transition().duration(1500) // instead of 2500
  .attr('x', (d) => d.x ?? 0)
  .attr('y', (d) => d.y ?? 0)
```

but that's of course not a universal solution, and it kind of moves around haphazardly. I'd rather have a way to interpolate the re-positioning with the translate so it smoothly grows and pans to be centered without going off-screen. Is this possible? I'm aware of d3.interpolate and scaleExtent/translateExtent but am stumped on how to use them - so far I haven't figured out how to account for both repositioning and translate/scale at the same time.

Other relevant bits of code:

```
<svg
  style={{ borderStyle: "Solid", borderWidth: "1px" }}
  width="800"
  height="600"
  onClick={onClickHandler} <!-- this just switches to the subgraph -->
>
  <g />
</svg>
```

```
const gr = d3.select('g');
const rects = gr.selectAll<SVGSVGElement, ElkNode>('rect').data(elkGraph.children, (d) => d.id);

// update, enter, exit logic omitted; see above for position update
// offset and scale logic omitted

gr.transition().duration(2500)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${xCenterOffset}, ${yCenterOffset}) scale(${scaleFactor})`)
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimal reproducible example. This will make it for others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also your problem is not completely clear to me. Please explain it in more detail. Are you zooming into the existing tree or are you rendering the selected subtree separately by itself?

Comment: Rendering the selected subtree, but the nodes have the same ids as before, so that is how d3 knows to transition them.